# IE7 add element and value to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-7

I am declaring an array as such

```
var positions = [];
```

or

```
var positions = new array();
```

either way works

Later in the script a value is added as such

```
positions[0].top = 0;
```

Everything is fine in every browser except ie7 gets this error

```
Error: Unable to set value of the property 'top': object is null or undefined
```

Is there another way that I should populate the arra in ie7?

Answer (score 1):

You want the javascript function push(). You should be doing it like this across the board.

```
  var positions = ["something", "somethign else"];
  positions.push("something new");
```

`.top` is a property of most dom elements I believe, but not appropriate for this array.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add an object value instead of pushing to an array. If you're trying to use an array, then you'll need to use .push():

```
var positions = [];
    positions.push(value);
    positions.push(value2);
```

So, in the code above, `value` will be available at `positions[0]` and `value2` will be available at `positions[1]`.

However, if you're trying to create an object that you can access like so:

```
position.top;
position.bottom;
etc.
```

Then you'll need to instead create an object:

```
var positions = {};
    positions.top = 0;
    positions.bottom = 20;
```